# Dubbed line in The Parallax View

Tags: dialogue, dubbing, the-parallax-view

In a scene from *The Parallax View*, William Daniels’ character is berating Warren Beatty’s. He tells him:

> You’re just a third-rate journalist from Oregon, or wherever the hell you’re from.

The second half of the line – staring with “Oregon” – was clearly changed in post-production (one of the many editing failures in this movie) and I was just curious if the reason for the change was known, or if it’s known what the character was originally saying.

A cursory Google search didn’t turn up anything but I thought maybe it might have been in a book or something?

Comment: The book features a handful of NYTimes journalists, so it certainly isn't in there: https://www.criminalelement.com/page-to-screen-the-parallax-view/ The movie is a significant rewrite from the book.

Comment: Was it definitely changed or merely dubbed? There’s lots of reasons to dub a line besides changing it. One reason to dub is if the actor said something different from the script, so even if the dub is different from the location sound, it might have been fixed instead of changed. One example of changed dialog via dub is the line from *Dr. Strangelove* that was originally "A guy could have a pretty good night in Dallas with all the stuff" was changed to “Vegas" because the movie came out soon after John F. Kennedy was assassinated in Dallas.

Comment: @ToddWilcox the actor was definitely saying something other than “Oregon”